# Trying to implement react-navigation in my React Native Toyota app

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have been trying for days now to add screens with different cars to the navigation stack. help??

[My Expo Snack Link](https://snack.expo.dev/@codelikeagirl91/toyota)

```
app.js
    import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
    import CarsList from './components/CarsList';
    import Header from './components/Header';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Header />
          <CarsList />
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    });
```

Comment: You have not setup the navigation, you will have to use a stack navigator , checkout the example here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.